# 'Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.' When iterating divs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I receive this warning:
"Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `Todo`. in TodoItem (at ToDo.js:14)"

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoItem from './todoItem.js'

class Todo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    elements: [
      {title: 'Zrobić zakupy'},
      {title: 'Opłacić domenę'},
    ]
  }

  render() {
    const elements =this.state.elements.map((e, index) => {
      return <TodoItem element={e} i ={index}/>
    })
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <h1>Todo app</h1>
        {elements}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Todo;
```

```
import React from 'react';

const TodoItem = props => {
  return <div className="card" key={props.i}>{props.element.title}</div>;
}

export default TodoItem;
```

I cannot iterate divs in proper way.
I find out the key values was implement correctly.
why I am getting warning?

Comment: add a key on TodoItem and not inside this component returned element

Answer (score 0):

You must assign the key property where you use the component `TodoItem`, instead of where you define the component.

```
  return <TodoItem element={e} key={index} i={index}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the key in the following code

```
<TodoItem element={e} i ={index} key={index}/>
```